# Need help for resolving merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge

I am learning git.
I have a file called README which contains `a,b,c,d`. I created four branches out of master. User on branch 1 changes `a` to `p`, user on branch 2 changes `b` to `q`,  user on branch 3 changes `c` to `r` and  user on branch 4 changes `d` to `s`. Now when I try to merge all branches to master I get merge conflict. How do I merge all branches to master without conflict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 3):

Look in the conflicted files and decide which parts of the code between the

```
<<<<<<
====
>>>>>>
```

symbols you want to keep. Don't forget to delete them afterwards!

Then do `git commit -a`.